# How to check that class method require parameter

Tags: php, class, object

For example there is Foo class object. Not try-catch expression

```
class Foo {
   function Bar($a){
   }
}

$foo = new Foo();

if(hasRequiredParams(Object $foo, MethodName 'Bar')){
   do something;
}
```

Comment: What you mean by "require parameter"?

Comment: @hindmost I mean that if you ll try to call $foo->bar(), you ll get exception... so how to prevent calling this function

Comment: Have you tried use [variable-length arguments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list)?

Comment: @hindmost no because if function already written and it cannot be changed, how can you check it outside? But that you mentioned above is advisable in some cases...

Comment: `class Foo {
   function Bar($a = null){
   }
}
`

Comment: thanks, but cbuckley has already given correct answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with [reflection](http://php.net/book.reflection):

```
class Foo {
    function Bar($a) {
    }
}

$rc = new ReflectionClass('Foo');
$rm = $rc->getMethod('Bar');
var_dump($rm->getNumberOfRequiredParameters()); // 1
```

However, just because you can do this, it doesn't mean you should. There may be reasons for needing to inspect the method signature at run-time, but in most cases you shouldn't be basing your application logic on this information.

Comment: Ok... Thanks...
I think it might be useful in zf2 and doctrine... I tried to write hydrator which will recursively call get methods on entity, but some of them has required params... it can resolve question.